# getting ready to go or getting myself ready to go

Tags: word-usage, reflexive-pronouns

I want to go out with someone. Currently, I am wearing my clothes and making my makeup.

Shall I use *myself* in this context?

Which one is correct:

> I am getting ready to go out.

or

> I am getting myself ready to go out.

Comment: Archaic [feminine]: I'm putting my face on.

Comment: The light verb for *makeup* is *do*, not *make*.

Comment: *right verb, perhaps? @snailboat

Comment: No, light verb.  Please look up light verb constructions.

Comment: If a native speaker doesn't know the term, what are the chances a learner will? @snailboat

Comment: Most likely a learner won't know the term, but the odds are probably better for a learner than a native speaker.  Native speakers of English typically know next to zero grammar, and the few terms they know, they've learned poorly at best. Learners, in contrast, tend to have more explicit grammar knowledge. In any case, I'm of the belief that people can *learn*.  Rather than objecting to an unfamiliar term representing an unfamiliar concept, the reader can simply *look it up* or *ask further questions*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct and understandable in that you have a few more things to do before you go out the door.

Using the reflexive **myself** would draw more attention to your person.

I would interpret

> getting **myself** ready

to mean: your **hair**, your **dress**, your **makeup**, things more **personal to you**

> getting ready

could mean getting your keys, turning off the lights, checking the cat's milk supply, but can also mean things about yourself.

In math speak, **getting myself ready** is a subset of **getting ready**

In terms of usage, using **myself** is more AmE, in BrE one would usually not want to draw that kind of attention to oneself.

Comment: Your last sentence is interesting. I've never heard that before and would be interested in some reference

Comment: I've had female AmE friends use **myself**, whenever talking to a native BrE any sort of grooming or toiletry reference tends to be indirect, though as a group, females may say "We're getting **ourselves** together", but I've not heard **myself**, just "I'm *(still)* getting ready"

Comment: Bogus AmE/BrE distinction, IMO.  http://alanfrostphotography.com/tag/sherlock-holmes/

Comment: @TRomano Please find a relevant reference regarding **grooming or toiletry** as I have posted.

Comment: So @Peter it's anecdotal, based on an extremely small sample size, and of questionable scope...?

Comment: Based on experience, would not say small sample size, I've been in the UK for 10 years

Comment: Okay, fab, terrific, now could you back up your decade long experience with a verifiable reference? Since I have had exposure to speakers of BrE for three decades and never noticed a distinction.

Answer (score 0):

First, in English, we use the verb *do*, not *make*, in the phrase *doing my makeup*. However *do* is ambiguous as lots of times it just defaults to the meaning of some other verb that is used in the same context. Another common phrase is *putting my makeup on*.

So you could say:

> Currently I am wearing my clothes and doing my makeup/putting my makeup on.

You can say either

> I am getting ready to go out

or

> I am getting myself ready to go out.

*Myself* is a reflexive pronoun.

The choice depends on whether you want to make the verb reflexive (refer to yourself explicitly). You might want to make it reflexive when the preparation refers to actions that involve getting your *own person* ready (such as when you put on your makeup, dress yourself, bathe yourself, brush your teeth, brush your hair, put on perfume...). But it's not necessary.

If you are getting *something else* ready, such as gathering up items you need (phone, umbrella, keys...); or looking for items (shoes, keys, phone...), or getting *someone else* ready (the baby, the babysitter...); or anything besides reflexive activities, then that would not call for a reflexive pronoun.

Since you are still in the act of *doing your makeup* or *putting your makeup on*, you might wish to say *getting myself ready*. But you do not have to. In fact, if you want to hide the fact that you are (still) getting dressed or putting on your makeup, you can not use the reflexive *myself* and whoever you are talking to will probably assume otherwise (unless they are in the same room or you let them know in some other way).